# Internet Explorer 10 blurred scaling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, winjs

In my Windows 8 javascript app I have elements which are toggled into visibility when a button is clicked. I gave them a subtle animation to make the experience less linear using CSS keyframes, like so:

```
@keyframes visible {
    0% {transform: scale(0.1);
        opacity: 0;}
    80% {transform: scale(1.1)}
    100% {transform: scale(1);
          opacity: 1;}
}
```

This works fine, however it seems that scaling the element back down from 1.1 to 1 causes the content to blur until a mouse/touch event is registered. This doesn't look very good, and I was wondering if there are any little tricks to avoid this, or if there isn't is there any alternative I could use to get the desired result without blurring the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself by adding `font-size:inherit;` into the last animation frame. Now my text isn't blurred and neither are my background images!